# Enabled custom systemd service is not started on boot

Tags: boot, systemd, services

My goal is to create a file after every boot. Code below is a simplified version.

This is the `systemd` service unit file in `/lib/systemd/system/createfile.service`:

```
[Unit]
Description=Creates a file

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=touch /home/ubuntu/halfdan_was_here

[Install]
WantedBy=multi.user.target
```

- When executing `systemctl start createfile.service` manually then `/home/ubuntu/halfdan_was_here` is created as expected.
- When using `journalctl -u createfile.service` the execution of the service is reported

  ```
  $ journalctl -u createfile.service

  -- Logs begin at Thu 2022-09-01 12:58:03 CEST, end at Thu 2022-09-01 14:11:33 CEST. --
  Sep 01 14:01:24 runner-0 systemd[1]: Started Creates a file.
  Sep 01 14:01:24 runner-0 systemd[1]: createfile.service: Succeeded.
  ```
- After using `systemctl enable createfile.service` the service is shown as "enabled":

  ```
    $ systemctl status createfile.service

    ● createfile.service - Creates a file
         Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/createfile.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
         Active: inactive (dead)
  ```
- After deleting the file manually and doing a reboot the file is not created. `journalctl -u createfile.service` also doesn't show that it was executed.
- I also played around with different settings for `Requires` & `After` but without luck.

Thanks for any suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

> My goal is to create a file after every boot.

I'm doing the same thing, and I ended up taking the easy way, and have added this to my user's crontab (using `crontab -e`):

```
@reboot touch /home/am/last_reboot
```

It seems creating a systemd service might be slight overkill for touching a file on boot. The beauty of crontab here is its absolute simplicity, and this works for me!

Comment: omg, now I feel stupid. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Don't.. We learn all the time, don't we? 